# Myisam table unreadable after sort_buffer_size too small error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, myisam, repair

I was trying to run OPTIMIZE TABLE on a that's about 200GB 1billion record big, but couple second after the operation, I was giving a sort_buffer_size too small error and now the table showing as 0 row in phpmyadmin, and still have 200gb in size. I can't read anything from it.
Tried to bump the sort_buffer_size to 1gb and ran the OPTIMIZE again, but the operation is done in seconds with no success in restoring....

Now I start running REPAIR TABLE. Since this is probably gonna take days to complete, I just want to make sure I am heading in the right direction before wasting time on it. Seems to me the key file is broken? Anyone with similar experience that could help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You should accept previously asked questions to appeal to wider audience. Sucks when stuff like what you are describing happens, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :x not really familiar how the whole stackoverflow rating system works. I probably need to hang out here more often XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question if anyone happened to had stupid things happened like me.
Yes repair table works, and to make it quick use REPAIR TABLE name QUICK to just quickly rebuild the key without touching other stuff in the table. 300mil record took me 1 day to finish.